# VB.NET write in a text file located in web url

Tags: vb.net

I am tried to write/edit the text file that is located in a web url.

like....

```
    Dim address As String = "http://www.website.com/path/to/textfile.txt"
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(client.OpenWrite(address))
    writer.WriteLine("this is a line")
```

for your information the web folder has writable permission.

Problem is, this code could not write into the file.

What should I do ?

Comment: You can only read from the web, never write.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierJacot-Descombes. Is it possible to create or delete the file located in web url ?

Comment: If you could do that, then just anybody could just delete or overwrite the contents of web-pages. Google for "how to upload file to web"

Answer (score 0):

You can not write files to a web URL, but if the URL were a FTP URL you can download the files, edit them and upload them again, all from the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are writing a path like "`http://...`" which should bring you to another machine somewhere. In most cases the owner of this other machine does not want you to fiddle with his/her files. Hence they are read-only for you; you cannot create, update or delete them.

In the case `www.website.com` leads to Your machine doesn't matter. You talk (through http) to the machine as if it is somewhere else; disregarding who owns it or even if it the very same machine your are programming at.

Files are something that exists in *your file system*, typically on a hard drive. They are identified by a path and a filename and (depending on operating system) can look like `C:\MyFolder\MyFile.txt` or `\\AServer\MyShare\MyFolder\MyFile.txt`.
You have full (well, you might not have but let's not discuss that part) access to your harddrive and your files to do what you like.